# Visual Studio 2012 OLEDB connection

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have this code that I am using in visual studio 2012 to populate a combobox from data in a sql database.  Every time I try to debug it I get the exception at the for loop of a null reference exception.  I am hoping someone can help me figure out what it is I am missing here.

Private Sub StationList_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StationList.Click

```
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\hendera2\Desktop\StationEquip.accdb"
    Dim Mystr As String = "SELECT DISTINCT Location FROM StationEquipment"
    Dim Myadapter As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim Mydataset As New DataSet()



    Try
        cn.Open()

        Myadapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(Mystr, cn.ConnectionString)
        Myadapter.Fill(Mydataset, Mystr)




        Dim dr As DataRow

        For Each dr In Mydataset.Tables("StationEquipDataSet").Rows
            Me.StationList.Items.Add(dr("Location"))
        Next

        cn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Cannot Open connection")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the "StationEquipDataSet" data table name to "StationEquipment"
You're mismatching the table name, this is causing the null reference when you're trying to access the rows of this table, because it doesnt exists

Comment: I tried stepping into it and the dataset gives me the In order to evaluate an indexed property the property must be qualified and the arguments must be explicitly defined by the user.  I think then that there is a clean connection to the database but not to the records in the table.  I am not sure how to rectify that

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I can't see your database, or the records it's pulling, but I would try adding this to elemenate the possibility of trying to reference a null value:

```
If Mydataset.Tables("StationEquipDataSet").Rows.Count > 0 Then
    For Each dr In Mydataset.Tables("StationEquipDataSet").Rows
        Me.StationList.Items.Add(dr("Location"))
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you got the name wrong in the `Mydataset.Tables("StationEquipDataSet")` expression.

To find out whether the dataset really does contain your table, and to find out what would be the correct name to use as index, you could try to insert these lines just before the loop:

```
    Console.WriteLine(MyDataSet.Tables.Count);
    for (var i = 0; i > MyDataSet.Tables.Count;i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyDataSet.Tables[0].TableName);
    }
```

This would for instance write the amount of tables and the table names to the console.